# How to Stop a UIScrollView from Swallowing Touches

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiscrollview, touch

I have `UIScrollView` that has many subviews. When I scroll, I want to tap on a subview which I want to be dragged. Is there a possible way to make the `UIScrollView` stop from swallowing touches? Or is it possible to start new touch when you cancel the scrolling (like what it scrolls and I tapped on it, the subview will be tapped as well so I can drag it out)?

Answer (score 2):

Subclass UIScrollView and override the `- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view` method. Here's an example to allow uibutton touches to pass through:

```
#import "scrollViewWithButtons.h"

@implementation scrollViewWithButtons

- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view
{
    return ![view isKindOfClass:[UISlider class]];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! But lets say, the `UISlider` is a `UIImageView` but I have many `UIImageView`s, how should I approach it then?

Comment: I have `UIScrollView` which has `UIView`s in it. The `UIView` has `UIImageView` which can be selected and can be dragged. Now, the problem is, when I scroll and tap on it again to cancel/stop the scrolling, I also want to check if I tapped on the `UIImageView` so I can drag it out. But what happening is, the scroll just stops. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a way to scroll inside a uiscrollview (other then the default scrolling)

Comment: I don't want to scroll, I just I want to make a touch event inside the scrollview if possible. Also, is there a way to know if the user is dragging or swiping, etc.? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you want something similar to springboard? You can drag items by long pressing on them to "grab" them but otherwise swiping causes scrolling?

Comment: If you don't want to scroll at all via touch, make your subviews subclasses of UIControl or place them inside UIControls or add UIGestureRecognizers to them. Then set scrollview.canCancelContentTouches = NO.