# UIButton does not work in uiscrollView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have a `scrollView` that has a `UIView` as subview. This has as `UIView` subview a `UIButton`. Only the `scrollView` is connected to the outlet, the rest is all in code. The button does not respond to touches, not turns blue when touched. What can I do to make it work?

This is the code:

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
       [super viewDidLoad];

      //......

      self.buttonHome = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
      [self.buttonHome addTarget:self action:@selector(pressedHome:)
                                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
      //....
      self.containerView =[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.scrollView.frame];
      self.containerView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

      [self.scrollView addSubview:self.containerView];
      [self.containerView addSubview:self.buttonHome];
  }

  -(void) pressedHome:(id)sender{
         //....
  }
```

Comment: I simulate the work u mentioned but it is working correctly for me

Comment: For me doesn't work. Without the UIView worked all perfectly, but this UIView is necessary for zoom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolve it

```
  - (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view
  {
       return ![view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]];
  }
```

Since the problem is to put a button UIButton

Answer (score 4):

You must set content size of your view. That must be greater than or equal to the content size of scrollView.

Because default size of your view is 320*480 (3.5" retina) and 320*568 (4" retina). So increasing height of view as-

self.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 700);

Then adding this as the subview of your scrollView.

will get you to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your scrollview isn't swallowing the touches:
Check this other SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480201/how-to-stop-a-uiscrollview-from-swallowing-touches)

Answer (score -1):

Make containerView view height same as scrollView Height.